# JS ES6 превратить экземпляр класса в key: value object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть класс

```
class Data {
    constructor(arg0, arg1) {
        this.arg0 = arg0;
        this.arg1 = arg1;
    }
}
```

Как представить экземпляр этого класса `new Data('arg0', 1)`, в виде `{arg0: 'arg0', arg1: 1}`?

Comment: Где именно ты хочешь его представить в таком виде?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(new Data('arg0', 1));`

Comment: @Grundy хочу, чтобы `const data = new Data('arg0', 1);` было тем же самым, что и `const data = {arg0: 'arg0', arg1: 1);`

Comment: @iamsolame, а почему ты думаешь, что это не то же самое?

Comment: @Igor, это то понятно, но мне вот как в комменте выше надо, а то уволят к чертям собачьим  :c

Comment: @Grundy, А это то же самое? :O

Comment: @iamsolame, а какие ты видишь отличия? :-)

Comment: мне нравится ваш обмен вопросами. @iamsolame, Объясните, какую задачу Вы пытаетсь решить.

Comment: @Igor, я работаю с React Native, занимаюсь двусторонним взаимодействием JS и Java. Туда и обратно я могу передать только key: value объекты и массивы, типы содержимого при этом ограничены: string, number, boolean и в общем всё

Comment: @Igor, я очень много чего неправильно написал и сейчас быстренько стараюсь переделать. Если я передам экземпляр такого класса вместо обычного объекта у меня ничего не упадёт?

Comment: _Если я передам экземпляр такого класса вместо обычного объекта у меня ничего не упадёт?_ - так ты попробуй

Comment: @Grundy, да, экземпляр такого класса - это и есть object!

Comment: то есть проблемы, которую ты пытался решить - нет?

Comment: @Grundy больше нет) Суть её была в непонимании того, что объект и экземпляр такого класса - одно и то же